# How to move another activity in webview redirecting url

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview to show a webpage. In that webpage button click event i'm redirecting to another page. From there another button click event im redirection to 3rd page. Instead of redirecting to 3rd page i need to show my next activity.

I'm using the following code but my first page itself not loading

```
            @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvLogin);

    setContentView(webview);    
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        // Override URL

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if(url.equals("http://My 3rd page redirecting URL"))
            {                       
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APImages.class);
                startActivity(i);                   
            }           
            return true;
        }

    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://Default URL to load first time");

}
```

Please tell me how to preceed it?

Comment: Please post code of your webview's initialization and loading. It's seems problem is not in this part.

Comment: If i remove this code my all the three web pages are working. but i need to show activityB during redirecting second url

Comment: I update the code. Please check it.

Comment: check answer of @Shaiful. I think it's correct.

Comment: No its not working. check my comment for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false when you are not handle the event. This is from the [WebClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) reference.

```
True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
```

Your code should be like this.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // Override URL

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if(url.equals("http://My 3rd page redirecting URL"))
        {                       
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APImages.class);
            startActivity(i);                   
            return true;
        }           
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: I tried as u specified. I got the text dispalying as "Obect moved **here**" with the word "here" as a link. but if i click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    if(url.equals("http://My 3rd page redirecting URL"))
    {                       
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APImages.class);
        startActivity(i);                   
    } else {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, for this it doesn't show anything. Just empty page(Activity) is showing.

Comment: One more thing, while opening the emulator and during first run of my app it asking security certificate with continue buttons and its redirecting to https page. but while installing the app in same emulator next time its not asking such things.

Answer (score 0):

Try onLoadResource. This should work for webview. Sometimes onOverride function doesnt work especially when you are calling an intent.